# Is my custom login safe?

Tags: python, django, security

I have created my own custom login, I'm not using django's login.

This is my **models.py**:

```
class TipeUser(models.Model):
    tipe = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
class User(models.Model):

    user = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    id_tipe_user = models.ForeignKey(TipeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My **views.py**:

```
    def login(request):

        context={}  
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)

    def validate(request):
        if request.method=='POST':
            nameUser = request.POST.get('nameUser')
            passwordUser = request.POST.get('passwordUser')
            password = md5.new(passwordUser).hexdigest()
         try:
            userAdmin = User.objects.get(user=nameUser, password=password, id_tipe_user=1, state=1)
            request.session['nameUser'] = userAdmin.user
            return redirect('home')
         except User.DoesNotExist: 
             message= "User/Password wrong !!"
              context = {
                 'message': message,
              }
               return render(request, 'login.html', context)

    def home(request):

        if 'nameUser' not in request.session:

            return render(request, 'login.html', {})
        else:
           return render(request, 'myMenu.html', context)

def logout(request):

    if 'nameUser' in request.session:

        #delete session
        del request.session['nameUser']
        #redirect to login
        return redirect('login')


    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

I would like a second opinion, is this good practice? I am totally safe here, or do I need to revise my code?

Comment: [Have a look](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10)

Comment: Is my custom login safe? -> NO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not.

- Using MD5 hashing for passwords has not been secure practice for at least 15 years.
- You shouldn't put model instances into the session, as they will not be "live", i.e. if the user in the database changes, the object in your session will still have the old data.
- You're assuming there's a `TipeUser` with the ID 1 (whatever that means).
- You're querying a `state` CharField with an integer `1`.
- Probably other things, but I'm not going to bother enumerating them, because –

To put it bluntly, you're reinventing the perfectly good wheels Django has provided for sessions and users. Why are you doing this? If you need extra data on your user model, [there's support for that already](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/).